# Using Tkinter to create a GUI that creates a folder and unwrap a ZIP file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, zip

Hello fellow programmers,

Im trying to make a GUI with Tkinter. This is the first time that Ive used Tkinter, and Ive run into some issues. The script and GUI should do the following:

1. Ask user (via entry and 'ok' button) to enter the name of the working folder. Result ->  Create the newly made folder on the desktop of the system.
2. Select an OWL file (which is a zip-file) via TkFileDialog.
   Result -> unwrap the selected zip-file in the folder that has been created in step 1.

The script Ive written so-far using online tutorials:

```
    import Tkinter
    import Tkconstants
    import tkFileDialog
    import zipfile
    from Tkinter import *
    import os

    class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

      def __init__(self, root):

        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        root.configure(background='lightgrey')
        root.wm_title("Audit tool: Thickness of pavement")
        root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(500, 500))

        Label_1 = Message(root, text="Step 1. Please fill in the name of the output folder and click on 'create'. The output folder will be created in the desktop folder:", width=380,)
        Label_1.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

        Entry1 = Entry(root)
        Entry1.grid(row=2, sticky=E)

        folder_location = '~/Desktop/' + Entry1.get()

        def createname():

          return os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser(folder_location))

        button_1 = Button(root, text="Create", command=createname)
        button_1.grid(row=2, column =1, sticky=W)

        Label_3 = Message(root, text="Step 2. Please select the OWL file:", width=300,)
        Label_3.grid(row=5, sticky=W)

        button_2 = Button(self, text='Click here to select the OWL file', command=self.askopenfilename)
        button_2.grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W)

        self.file_opt = options = {}
        options['defaultextension'] = '.owl'
        options['filetypes'] = [('all files', '.*'), ('owl files', '.owl')]
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['initialfile'] = 'Title_of_OWL-file.ccr'
        options['parent'] = root
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'

        self.dir_opt = options = {}
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['mustexist'] = False
        options['parent'] = root

      def askopenfile(self):

        return tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='r', **self.file_opt)

      def askopenfilename(self):

        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')

        if filename:
          return zip_ref.extractall(folder_location)

    if __name__=='__main__':
      root = Tkinter.Tk()
      TkFileDialogExample(root).grid()
      root.mainloop()
```

The problem probably lies within the third use of 'folder_location'. Since I am relatively new to the Python language, I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

Thank you for your help and time!

Yours truly,

Ruben van der Heijden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have defined the variable `folder_location` *only* in the local scope of your `TkFileDialogExample.__init__` method. As a result, it is not accessible to any of the other methods of your class. If you *do* want it to be accessible, then you'll want to set it as an attribute of your class using the `self` keyword.

```
def __init__(self, root):

    # Stuff

    self.folder_location = os.path.join('~', 'Desktop', Entry1.get())
```

Then you can access it from your `TkFileDialogExample.askopenfilename` method:

```
def askopenfilename(self):

    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**self.file_opt)
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(filename, 'r')

    if filename:
      return zip_ref.extractall(self.folder_location)
```

*Side Note*: In general, it is best to use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct file paths from strings.